# Am I allowed to store data retrieved from Facebook connect on my server?

Tags: facebook, store

Am I allowed to permanently store data I retrieve from Facebook connect about a user (eg. firstname, lastname etc.) on my server if my application requires it to function? If the user deinstalls the app I will remove it again of course. I have heard this is not allowed, but could not find the right paragraph in their terms of use.

Comment: Tthis question is off-topic because it's a legal issue.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about a legal issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please see the section entitled *Storing and Using Data You Receive From Us* in the [Facebook Platform Policies](https://developers.facebook.com/policy/) page.  The applicable item is:

> You may cache data you receive through
>   use of the Facebook API in order to
>   improve your application’s user
>   experience, but you should try to keep
>   the data up to date. This permission
>   does not give you any rights to such
>   data.

So, no, you do not own the data nor are you allowed to use it as the "data of record" - i.e. your official permanent copy.  You are required to at most cache the data temporarily and refresh it frequently.  Facebook remains the system of record and official repository for the data.

Comment: Let's say a user creates an account through FB connect (he authorizes the app and I retrieve email, first and lastname and a couple of other infos), would I now be allowed to store this information in my DB as a record or would I only be allowed to store the FB user id of the person? Basically I am just caching the data if there is a function that checks back with FB every now and then and updates it. Might be a border case, but otherwise I wonder how all the sites work that offer sign up through FB connect

Comment: If you collect that data in a form you host, keep it.  If you retrieve it from FB, then go back and update is periodically.  If I change my email or name on FB, I want 3rd party sites using FB data to propagate the changes in a timely manner - no more than 24 hours.  For *any* data on FB that you collect which can subsequently be made private by the user, you need either to collect it in your own forms or make it so that restricting the data on FB causes the data to be purged from your site.  That's my interpretation, anyway.

Comment: @T.Rob What about their public status? Can we store their public updates into our server to serve them later?

Comment: As a rule, it's insane to seek or give advice on reuse of copyrighted content on social media when the desired answer is "yes." Per my interpretation of the Facebook terms, the answer is "no."  But IANAL (I am not a lawyer) so the only credible answer I can possibly give would be the more conservative "no" option.  If you find someone who says "yes," then "some SO user said it would be OK" is not a credible defense in a court of law and unless your web site is rolling in money, you have lost just by being taken to court.  Either seek qualified advice or don't do it.

Answer (score 0):

Now you can, in Platform Policy https://developers.facebook.com/policy/ does not explicitly say that you can't store the data!