# Database Based Facebook Connect

Tags: database, facebook

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Am I allowed to store data retrieved from Facebook connect on my server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4760891/am-I-allowed-to-store-data-retrieved-from-Facebook-connect-on-my-server)

Can We store Facebook login information to our database so that if user can come to revisit our site he can automatically log in to Facebook.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

if user has accepted your app request and sharing his information with you. that information you can store in your db but his login credentials you can't save its due to security. if user is already logged in facebook and that time he visit your site that thing you can manage he will be auto logged in to your site.

Hope you understand if you need more clarification please visit facebook API.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

No, it is not possible. You can, however, check if user is logged in ([FB.getLoginStatus()](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.getLoginStatus/)) and ask said user to log in if he/she is not ([FB.login()](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.login/))