# how to store facebook login details into our sql server

Tags: javascript, facebook

I am stuck at 1 point on how to integrate Facebook using javascript to my application/website. User can login to our site using our site registration and login. But if user wants to get login through facebook then that user should be logged in to our application.

If user is logged in to facebook and goes to my site for the first time then javascript code should save his all details into our database and then allow user to access our site.

If user login from facebook now and goes to our application then he will just get logged in to our site as his details were present in database as we have saved his basic details such as username,firstname,lastname,country,state,city,gender etc details

Is there any way out to get out of this problem.

Comment: You are not allowed to store facebook data permanently other than to cache it for usability http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4760891/am-i-allowed-to-store-data-retrieved-from-facebook-connect-on-my-server

Comment: How do you want to save data to a db via JavaScript? This is not working without any kind of middleware!